# Error when including file in Prestashop hookActionProductSave hook

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I'm trying to create a hook in Prestashop (1.7), using this hook: 
hookActionProductSave

The hook is called, but I get the following error: 
Form update errors

That's all I get, and I saw it was because I was including some files like this:

```
require("controllers/admin/classes/error.class.php");
```

In other hooks it works, for example hookDisplayFooter and  hookActionPaymentConfirmation, only not in the product save... I've tried a lot of things, changint he path, having a full path, really a lot of things and I can't figure it out what's causing this.

Anyone has an idea of what the problem may be and how can it be fixed? Would apreciate the help, thank you! :)

Here is a bit of the code (I know I wont use the mail function, is just a test):

```
public function hookActionProductSave($params)
    {
        require("controllers/admin/classes/error.class.php");
        require("controllers/admin/classes/prestashop.general.php");

        $to      = 'email@test.com';
        $subject = 'Teste';
        $message =  print_r($params, true);

        $headers = 'From: teste@sss.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: teste@sss.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

       $functions = new General();
       $functions->productCreate($params);
       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `require` by `require_once`. When you save a product, most of the time you're in the administration. So this file `controllers/admin/classes/error.class.php` might already be loaded.

By using `require` you try to load it a second time and PHP do not allow this. To avoid this error you should use `require_once`:

```
public function hookActionProductSave($params)
{
    require_once("controllers/admin/classes/error.class.php");
    require_once("controllers/admin/classes/prestashop.general.php");

    $to      = 'email@test.com';
    $subject = 'Teste';
    $message =  print_r($params, true);

    $headers = 'From: teste@sss.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: teste@sss.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $functions = new General();
    $fuctions->productCreate($params);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient, thank you for the reply, that solved the problem right away! :D